# Two positive measures are mutually singular iff their sum is the variation of their difference

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two finitely positive measures on measurable space $\left ( X, \mathfrak{A} \right )$. Prove that
>   $$\mu \perp \nu \Leftrightarrow \mu + \nu = \left | \mu -\nu  \right |$$

I want to show that if $\mu \perp \nu$ then $\mu + \nu = \left | \mu -\nu  \right |$. I proved the inverse. I know $ \left | \mu -\nu  \right | \le \mu + \nu $, but I can't show the inverse equality.

Comment: I want to show that if $\mu \perp \nu$ then $\mu + \nu = \left | \mu -\nu  \right |$. I proved the inverse.
I know $ \left | \mu -\nu  \right | \le \mu + \nu $, but I can't show the inverse equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the signed measure $\lambda = \mu - \nu$. By the uniqueness statement in the Jordan decomposition theorem, $\lambda_{+} = \mu$ and $\lambda_{-} = \nu$. Thus $|\lambda| = \lambda_{+} + \lambda_{-} = \mu + \nu$.